# XHTML text in XML formatted with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create an XML file with a corresponding XSLT stylesheet. Everything sort of works okay, but...

...the nodes I'm outputting contain XHTML text inside them, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <snippet id="user_surname">
        <content>
            <h1>Some title here</h1>
            <p>Blah blah blah...</p>
        </content>
    </snippet>
    ...
</root>
```

Here's the corresponding XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="root/snippet">
      <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="content" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The issue I'm having, is that the h1 and p tags are not printed as h1 and p tags, but instead, as plain text without the tags.

How can I get my XSLT stylesheet to print these tags as is? I tried wrapping in CDATA tags, but it doesn't seem to help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`.  That should give you the nodes instead of the nodes as text.